# SQLITE linker error

Tags: c++, sqlite

I am trying to use the sqlite api, I've downloaded the .h and .cpp files from the official website, but I get errors like:

LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _sqlite3_open_v2 referenced in function _wmain

LNK2020: 1 unresolved externals

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "sqlite3.h"

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    sqlite3 *db;
    sqlite3_stmt *query;

    sqlite3_open_v2("test.db", &db, SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE | SQLITE_OPEN_CREATE, NULL);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: So, that tells you that you are not linking the sqlite library with your code. Do so, and the error will go away.

Comment: I've added the .dll to the resources, but the error is still here. What am I missing?

Comment: @userXXX If you added the DLL, that should be fine. How exactly is your compiler invoked? Please post the complete command line.

Comment: Do you mean this?: 

https://www.dropbox.com/s/ax8yidxw0478yma/console.txt

Comment: @userXXX No, I didn't mean the error message, I meant the invocation of the compiler. (Te magyar vagy?)

Comment: Where can I find it? :) (igen :) )

Comment: @userXXX Doesn't the IDE show it when you hit build? Usually it does show the compiler command. Maybe, logically, just above the error message.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33834/discussion-between-user2351645-and-h2co3)